# Vote buttons are distractingly bright in dark mode

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design, voting

I sincerely don't know why the design was changed. The current coloring is too light, making me feel that the button is "focused" and I will look at it unintentionally. I feel it really distracting when reading the posts. Please stop making cool decorations to achieve fake productivity. It would be great if you could provide an option to change to plain old settings trying something new.

OK, I know, we should provide advice not just complaints, so here is my advice: A light-color, probably **too light**, will put emphasis on "my votes". This is nonsense. Votes are something **NOT** important for myself at all after voting. I believe the purpose of voting is **to help others** finding potential great solutions more quickly. The important part is to **review** the contents of the answer **after** voting. Now it's distracting because it's too light.

For comparison: While sites like Reddit have been using orange color for a long time, their vote buttons are on the **bottom-left** corner. This makes it not as distracting as the current situation on StackOverflow when I just want to start reading the first sentence.

[image]

Comment: This seems to have been pushed out as part of the [changes described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/398314/1099857). As has been the norm lately, these types of network-wide style changes don't typically work exactly right for all sites' colour themes the first go around...

Comment: @HenryEcker: Thank you for the link. While I still prefer the light one on the left-hand side, the right one is still much better than the current orange color.

Comment: Hum, I'm a bit surprised about the "read the content after voting", I would expect people to read before voting, typo ?

Comment: It would be great if there are more themes to choose from; so, more people can be satisfied with the color.

Comment: @Tensibai: My argument doesn't match what I want to describe. I was reading old posts I upvoted a long time ago. Thanks for the catch. Updated with one single verb, what do you think?

Comment: FWIW, in "Force dark mode" in Chrome & related browsers, there's not much difference between the look of voted and unvoted here on MSO and other meta sites using a grey theme.

Comment: Every time a design change is implemented, there's always someone who wants to have the _option_ to apply the old design...

Implementing options like that is _not an option_. Every new design choice option _exponentially_ increases the number of UI variations that need to be tested.

Comment: Hello, we reverted the change for Stack Overflow only. The new updated vote button styling will be left as-is for the rest of the Stack Exchange network sites. Thank you.

Comment: @tanj92 Thanks for the revert on SO, but why not apply the same clear improvement everywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[tanj92](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/18740320/tanj92) posted the resolution as a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429387/vote-buttons-are-distractingly-bright-in-dark-mode#comment990279_429387), so I'll move it to an answer:

> Hello, we reverted the change for Stack Overflow only. The new updated vote button styling will be left as-is for the rest of the Stack Exchange network sites. Thank you.